# Можно ли автоматизировать создание новых листов и копирование информации в google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Есть множество таблиц, которые должны обновляться каждый день. Это очень большая рутина, которая достает. Я пока что не разобрался, как, хотя бы, в одной таблице автоматически создавать новые листы и копировать информацию с предыдущего.
Но возможно ли, в принципе, с помощью AppScripts гугла автоматизировать создание новых листов с заданными по шаблону названиями и копирования всей информации с предыдущего листа во множестве таблиц одновременно?

Answer (score 0):

Возможность копирования листов есть в Apps Script, для этого у нужного листа можно вызвать метод CopyTo:

```
function copyToSheet() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//Документ откуда копируем
const sourseSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Лист18');//Лист который копируем

const targetSS1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Вставить ID Spreadsheet')//Документ куда вставляем

sourseSheet.copyTo(targetSS1);//Операция копирования

  
  
}
```

По аналогии документов куда его нужно вставить может быть несколько